# django - showing just the select box value, no select box

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which represents a list of selected products, where each product is chosen from a select box. The select box chooses the PK of the product, but *shows* the PK + the Name of the product, something like: `E12 - Valve` or `E58 - Rotary nozzle`. Now, my specific situation is that I have a predefined set of products chosen for the user and the user cannot deviate from this selection of products. Thus, the user cannot be able to change the selected product. Further, this product form is an `inlineformset_factory`, not the main form.

I display my product form like this:

```
<table class="field_container" id="prodTable">
  <tr><th></th><th>CID</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
  {{ pform.management_form}}
  {% for form in pform %}
    <tr class="pform_set">
      {% for field in form %}
        <td class="product-item">{{ field }} {% if field.errors %} {{ field.errors }} {% endif %} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If I change `{{ field }}` to `{{ field.value }}` then all I get is `E12` which is the PK of the foreign model. However, I need it to show `E12 -- Valve`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) might work. Something like -

```
from your_module import Product

def get_product_string(value):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=value);
        return value + " -- " + product.name
    except DoesNotExist:
        return value
```

Then alter your template so instead of `{{ field.value }}` you do can do `{{ field.value|get_product_string }}`

Comment: Perhaps it is better to catch the specific exception, that is **DoesNotExist** exception

Comment: OK I've updated my answer to catch the specific exception. Thanks @bosco.